# How to retrieve a blob from mysql to picturebox when i click the datagrid in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

i'm making a profile database program in vb.net, every profile has a picture.its datatype is a blob How can i retrieve it to a picturebox from mysql?

Comment: You should take the [Tour] and learn how SO works.  You've been a member for almost a year, yet never accepted any answer and never voted.  Voting and accepting answers helps other users find good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple snippet that could help you:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select photo from Information where name='" & _
              DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value() & "'", con)
Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
        ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir :) gonna try this later

Comment: No problem friend ;)

Comment: Thanks again! it works like a charm! I have another question.. i can retrieve pictures(jpeg) now but there is another blob i want to retrieve in another picturebox, it is a fingerprint bitmap. I got an error when i use the same code as retrieving the Pictures(jpeg)